# Facebook FQL Stream Event ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to obtain the event id from the stream that a user responds. I only have the message "XPTO is going to an event."

The question is, **can I get the event ID querying the Stream table so I can get the name of the event?**

I'm using multyquery system so far.

Here is an example:

```
$queries = array(
            'query1' => 'SELECT app_data, app_id, post_id, share_count, created_time, message, permalink , actor_id, attachment, description, attribution, target_id, source_id, parent_post_id, filter_key, type FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE type = "newsfeed" AND uid = me()) ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 50',
            "query2" => "SELECT uid,first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT actor_id FROM #query1)",
            "query3" => "SELECT page_id, name FROM page WHERE page_id in (SELECT actor_id FROM #query1)"
        );
```

The query is to obtain the page and user names. Now i need to add the event name in case the user responds to an event.